# How can I install the Java Runtime Environment in Wine?

Tags: wine, java, jre

I have download a game and opened it with Wine, but it can't run this game, because the program required the *Java Runtime Environment 1.6.0*. The program recommends this link: *http://java.com/en/download/*, where I have downloaded this file. But when I opened its folder I didn't find any .exe file. How can I solve this problem so that I can run the game?

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit, and which Java download did you choose?

Comment: @Toroidal am running 64-bit and I tried all options but I didn't find .exe file anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You downloaded the wrong Java file, and the link you used didn't help. The correct link to download the Java file you wanted to run your game is: [Java Downloads for Windows](http://java.com/en/download/windows_manual.jsp?locale=en).

The installation instructions are available at the official [What is the offline method for downloading and installing Java for a Windows computer?](http://java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml) webpage.

Comment: This is the latest version though, and blackcornail said that they needed 1.6.0.

Comment: Why does blackcornail's link point to the latest version of Java Runtime Environment instead of simply sticking you with version 1.6.0 ? -- 1. Later versions of the Java JRE are almost always backwards compatible with older versions. 2. blackcornail may also require the latest version of Java JRE to run other apps. 3. The current version of Java has the latest security fixes.

Comment: Look, I just gave an answer which met their specifications. They said JRE 1.6.0, so that is what I linked to, that is all.

Comment: *The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.* Please take a look at this question: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

The link which you provided would have given you the Linux version. You need the Windows version, here is the download link for Java 1.6.0 as you specified you wanted: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u45-oth-JPR

You will need to click the `Accept License Agreement` radio button before it allows you to download. You will want the download called `jre-6u45-windows-x64.exe`.

Comment: You will also need to use the work around from https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40821#c18